# putting a null check in xsl

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have the below input xml and as i am working in xsl transformation using xalan api now the below is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Report xmlns:fpml="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/confirmation" xmlns="http://www.eurexchange.com/EurexIRSFullInventoryReport" name="CB202 Full Inventory Report">
  <reportNameGrp>
    <CM>
      <acctTypGrp name="A1">
        <ProductType name="OIS">
          <currTypCod value="EUR">
            <rateIndex name="EONIA">
              <rateIndexTenor name="1D">
                <idxSource>EONIA</idxSource>
                <CCPTradeId id="612822">
                  <fpml:dataDocument fpmlVersion="5-0">
                    <fpml:trade>
                      <fpml:tradeHeader>
                        <fpml:partyTradeIdentifier>
                          <fpml:partyReference href="CPTY_612822"></fpml:partyReference>
                          <fpml:tradeId tradeIdScheme=""></fpml:tradeId>
                        </fpml:partyTradeIdentifier>
                        <fpml:partyTradeIdentifier>
                          <fpml:partyReference href="PO_612822"></fpml:partyReference>
                          <fpml:accountReference href="ACC_612822"></fpml:accountReference>
                          <fpml:tradeId tradeIdScheme="">9786042-2</fpml:tradeId>
                          <fpml:versionedTradeId>
                            <fpml:tradeId tradeIdScheme="">612822</fpml:tradeId>
                            <fpml:version>1</fpml:version>
                          </fpml:versionedTradeId>
                        </fpml:partyTradeIdentifier>
                        <fpml:tradeDate>2013-05-21</fpml:tradeDate>
                        <fpml:clearedDate>2013-11-13</fpml:clearedDate>
                      </fpml:tradeHeader>
                      <fpml:swap>
                        <fpml:swapStream id="fixedLeg_612822">
                          <fpml:payerPartyReference href="CPTY_612822"></fpml:payerPartyReference>
                          <fpml:receiverPartyReference href="PO_612822"></fpml:receiverPartyReference>
                          <fpml:calculationPeriodDates id="fixedLegCalcPeriodDates_612822">
                            <fpml:effectiveDate>
                              <fpml:unadjustedDate>2013-05-23</fpml:unadjustedDate>
                              <fpml:dateAdjustments>
                                <fpml:businessDayConvention>NONE</fpml:businessDayConvention>
                              </fpml:dateAdjustments>
                            </fpml:effectiveDate>
                            <fpml:terminationDate>
                              <fpml:unadjustedDate>2015-05-23</fpml:unadjustedDate>
                              <fpml:dateAdjustments>
                                <fpml:businessDayConvention>MODFOLLOWING</fpml:businessDayConvention>
                                <fpml:businessCenters>
                                  <fpml:businessCenter>EUTA</fpml:businessCenter>
                                </fpml:businessCenters>
                              </fpml:dateAdjustments>
                            </fpml:terminationDate>
                            <fpml:calculationPeriodDatesAdjustments>
                              <fpml:businessDayConvention>MODFOLLOWING</fpml:businessDayConvention>
                              <fpml:businessCenters>
                                <fpml:businessCenter>EUTA</fpml:businessCenter>
                              </fpml:businessCenters>
                            </fpml:calculationPeriodDatesAdjustments>
                            <fpml:calculationPeriodFrequency>
                              <fpml:periodMultiplier>1</fpml:periodMultiplier>
                              <fpml:period>Y</fpml:period>
                              <fpml:rollConvention>23</fpml:rollConvention>
                            </fpml:calculationPeriodFrequency>
                          </fpml:calculationPeriodDates>
                          <fpml:paymentDates>
                            <fpml:calculationPeriodDatesReference href="fixedLegCalcPeriodDates_612822"></fpml:calculationPeriodDatesReference>
                            <fpml:paymentFrequency>
                              <fpml:periodMultiplier>1</fpml:periodMultiplier>
                              <fpml:period>Y</fpml:period>
                            </fpml:paymentFrequency>
                            <fpml:payRelativeTo>CalculationPeriodEndDate</fpml:payRelativeTo>
                            <fpml:paymentDaysOffset>
                              <fpml:periodMultiplier>1</fpml:periodMultiplier>
                              <fpml:period>D</fpml:period>
                              <fpml:dayType>Business</fpml:dayType>
                            </fpml:paymentDaysOffset>
                            <fpml:paymentDatesAdjustments>
                              <fpml:businessDayConvention>MODFOLLOWING</fpml:businessDayConvention>
                              <fpml:businessCenters>
                                <fpml:businessCenter>EUTA</fpml:businessCenter>
                              </fpml:businessCenters>
                            </fpml:paymentDatesAdjustments>
                          </fpml:paymentDates>
                          <fpml:calculationPeriodAmount>
                            <fpml:calculation>
                              <fpml:notionalSchedule>
                                <fpml:notionalStepSchedule>
                                  <fpml:initialValue>100000000.00</fpml:initialValue>
                                  <fpml:currency>EUR</fpml:currency>
                                </fpml:notionalStepSchedule>
                              </fpml:notionalSchedule>
                              <fpml:fixedRateSchedule>
                                <fpml:initialValue>0.01200000</fpml:initialValue>
                              </fpml:fixedRateSchedule>
                              <fpml:dayCountFraction>ACT/360</fpml:dayCountFraction>
                            </fpml:calculation>
                          </fpml:calculationPeriodAmount>
                        </fpml:swapStream>
                        <fpml:swapStream id="floatingLeg_612822">
                          <fpml:payerPartyReference href="PO_612822"></fpml:payerPartyReference>
                          <fpml:receiverPartyReference href="CPTY_612822"></fpml:receiverPartyReference>
                          <fpml:calculationPeriodDates id="floatingLegCalcPeriodDates_612822">
                            <fpml:effectiveDate>
                              <fpml:unadjustedDate>2013-05-23</fpml:unadjustedDate>
                              <fpml:dateAdjustments>
                                <fpml:businessDayConvention>NONE</fpml:businessDayConvention>
                              </fpml:dateAdjustments>
                            </fpml:effectiveDate>
                            <fpml:terminationDate>
                              <fpml:unadjustedDate>2015-05-23</fpml:unadjustedDate>
                              <fpml:dateAdjustments>
                                <fpml:businessDayConvention>MODFOLLOWING</fpml:businessDayConvention>
                                <fpml:businessCenters>
                                  <fpml:businessCenter>EUTA</fpml:businessCenter>
                                </fpml:businessCenters>
                              </fpml:dateAdjustments>
                            </fpml:terminationDate>
                            <fpml:calculationPeriodDatesAdjustments>
                              <fpml:businessDayConvention>MODFOLLOWING</fpml:businessDayConvention>
                              <fpml:businessCenters>
                                <fpml:businessCenter>EUTA</fpml:businessCenter>
                              </fpml:businessCenters>
                            </fpml:calculationPeriodDatesAdjustments>
                            <fpml:calculationPeriodFrequency>
                              <fpml:periodMultiplier>1</fpml:periodMultiplier>
                              <fpml:period>Y</fpml:period>
                              <fpml:rollConvention>23</fpml:rollConvention>
                            </fpml:calculationPeriodFrequency>
                          </fpml:calculationPeriodDates>
                          <fpml:paymentDates>
                            <fpml:calculationPeriodDatesReference href="floatingLegCalcPeriodDates_612822"></fpml:calculationPeriodDatesReference>
                            <fpml:paymentFrequency>
                              <fpml:periodMultiplier>1</fpml:periodMultiplier>
                              <fpml:period>Y</fpml:period>
                            </fpml:paymentFrequency>
                            <fpml:payRelativeTo>CalculationPeriodEndDate</fpml:payRelativeTo>
                            <fpml:paymentDaysOffset>
                              <fpml:periodMultiplier>1</fpml:periodMultiplier>
                              <fpml:period>D</fpml:period>
                              <fpml:dayType>Business</fpml:dayType>
                            </fpml:paymentDaysOffset>
                            <fpml:paymentDatesAdjustments>
                              <fpml:businessDayConvention>MODFOLLOWING</fpml:businessDayConvention>
                              <fpml:businessCenters>
                                <fpml:businessCenter>EUTA</fpml:businessCenter>
                              </fpml:businessCenters>
                            </fpml:paymentDatesAdjustments>
                          </fpml:paymentDates>
                          <fpml:resetDates id="floatingLegresetDates_612822">
                            <fpml:calculationPeriodDatesReference href="floatingLegCalcPeriodDates_612822"></fpml:calculationPeriodDatesReference>
                            <fpml:resetRelativeTo>CalculationPeriodEndDate</fpml:resetRelativeTo>
                            <fpml:fixingDates>
                              <fpml:periodMultiplier>0</fpml:periodMultiplier>
                              <fpml:period>D</fpml:period>
                              <fpml:businessDayConvention>PRECEDING</fpml:businessDayConvention>
                              <fpml:businessCenters>
                                <fpml:businessCenter>EUTA</fpml:businessCenter>
                              </fpml:businessCenters>
                              <fpml:dateRelativeTo href="floatingLegresetDates_612822"></fpml:dateRelativeTo>
                            </fpml:fixingDates>
                            <fpml:resetFrequency>
                              <fpml:periodMultiplier>1</fpml:periodMultiplier>
                              <fpml:period>Y</fpml:period>
                            </fpml:resetFrequency>
                            <fpml:resetDatesAdjustments>
                              <fpml:businessDayConvention>MODFOLLOWING</fpml:businessDayConvention>
                              <fpml:businessCenters>
                                <fpml:businessCenter>EUTA</fpml:businessCenter>
                              </fpml:businessCenters>
                            </fpml:resetDatesAdjustments>
                          </fpml:resetDates>
                          <fpml:calculationPeriodAmount>
                            <fpml:calculation>
                              <fpml:notionalSchedule>
                                <fpml:notionalStepSchedule>
                                  <fpml:initialValue>100000000.00</fpml:initialValue>
                                  <fpml:currency>EUR</fpml:currency>
                                </fpml:notionalStepSchedule>
                              </fpml:notionalSchedule>
                              <fpml:floatingRateCalculation>
                                <fpml:floatingRateIndex>EUR-EONIA-OIS-COMPOUND</fpml:floatingRateIndex>
                              </fpml:floatingRateCalculation>
                              <fpml:dayCountFraction>ACT/360</fpml:dayCountFraction>
                            </fpml:calculation>
                          </fpml:calculationPeriodAmount>
                        </fpml:swapStream>
                      </fpml:swap>
                      <fpml:documentation>
                        <fpml:masterAgreement>
                          <fpml:masterAgreementType masterAgreementTypeScheme="">ISDA</fpml:masterAgreementType>
                        </fpml:masterAgreement>
                        <fpml:contractualDefinitions>ISDA2006</fpml:contractualDefinitions>
                      </fpml:documentation>
                    </fpml:trade>
                    <fpml:party id="CPTY_612822">
                      <fpml:partyId>EUREX</fpml:partyId>
                      <fpml:partyName>EUREX</fpml:partyName>
                    </fpml:party>
                    <fpml:party id="PO_612822">
                      <fpml:partyId>BOSLO</fpml:partyId>
                      <fpml:partyName>plc.</fpml:partyName>
                    </fpml:party>
                    <fpml:account id="ACC_612822">
                      <fpml:accountId>BOSLO_A1</fpml:accountId>
                      <fpml:accountBeneficiary href="PO_612822"></fpml:accountBeneficiary>
                    </fpml:account>
                  </fpml:dataDocument>
                  <novDateTime>2013-11-13 17:50:44.773</novDateTime>
                </CCPTradeId>
              </rateIndexTenor>
            </rateIndex>
          </currTypCod>
        </ProductType>
      </acctTypGrp>
    </CM>
  </reportNameGrp>
</Report>
```

as you can see that from the above xml i am tring to read the value of tradeid scheme parameter that is 9786042-2 now i want to put a check that is value does not exixts in trade id scheme paremeter then null is dispalyed so for that i have come up with below xsl , but still for the cses where tradeid scheme paramtere value is not there null is not updated in those cases please advise how to populate null for those cases.

```
<!-- Main template starts -->

<xsl:template match="/eur:Report">
  <EurexMessage>
    <EurexFlows>
      <xsl:apply-templates select=".//eur:rateIndexTenor" />
      <!-- select="eur:reportNameGrp/eur:CM/eur:acctTypGrp/eur:ProductType/eur:currTypCod/eur:rateIndex/eur:rateIndexTenor" 
                    /> -->

    </EurexFlows>
  </EurexMessage>
</xsl:template>


<!-- sub template starts -->
<xsl:template match="eur:rateIndexTenor">
  <xsl:for-each select="eur:CCPTradeId">
    <EurexMessageObject>

      <!-- ####***** contact id is nul not displayd ****##### ----->
      <ContractID>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="fpml:dataDocument/*/*/fpml:partyTradeIdentifier/fpml:tradeId/@tradeIdScheme !=' '">
            <xsl:value-of
                select="fpml:dataDocument/*/*/fpml:partyTradeIdentifier[2]/fpml:tradeId" />
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="'null'" />
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </ContractID>
    </EurexMessageObject>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: In the future, please provide a _simplified_ version of your requirement. Digging through all this XML and lengthy XPaths is painful.

Comment: @JLRishe yeah agreed completely but please advise for the current problem thanks in advance

Comment: Oh, and if you want people to read your prose, they are more likely to do so if you use full stops and capital letters. It makes it look like you care.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `something != ' '` will produce

- `true` if there are *any* `something`s that are not equal to `' '` (a single space)
- `false` if *all* of the `something`s are equal to `' '`
- `false` if there are no `something`s

In your case, both of the `something`s are equal to `''` (empty string). Since both of these are unequal to `' '`, the result here is `true`.

If I am understanding correctly, you want to output the tradeId where the tradeIdScheme is not blank or whitespace, or output `null` if there is no such tradeId.

If so, this should do it:

```
<ContractID>
  <xsl:variable name="foundTradeId"
      select="fpml:dataDocument/*/*/fpml:partyTradeIdentifier/fpml:tradeId
                                         [normalize-space(@tradeIdScheme)]" />
  <xsl:value-of select="$foundTradeId" />
  <xsl:if test="not($foundTradeId)">null</xsl:if>
</ContractID>
```

Comment: yeah perfect your understanding is correct but the suggested implementation is not still working please advise , moreover i am using xslt1.0.

Comment: @sssddeewwqq What does "not working" mean? There was a capitalization error on one of the variable names. Was that the problem?